# Where can i find good study material for "MySQL Developers" certification?

Tags: mysql

Where can i find good study material for "MySQL   Developers" certification  ?. There is some material at http://education.oracle.com but is not free and is too expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should refer the book available in the market as one this
**[http://www.amazon.com/MySQL-5-0-Certification-Study-Guide/dp/0672328127/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1299972594&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127)**
will help you always.

and for same book you want free material its available here **http://www.chinastor.org/upload/2014-01/14011617231123.pdf**

prepare well.
best of luck.